# ¿Qué es lo que consume almacenamiento en una instancia RDS de AWS?

Tags: postgresql, aws, amazon, amazon-rds

Tengo una instancia RDS con PostgreSQL, usando el año de Free Tier que da AWS al crear un usuario nuevo.
La base es sencilla, tiene una sola tabla y dos registros por el momento. La enciendo cuando la necesito, aunque las horas que da el free tier son suficientes para tenerla corriendo las 24 horas. Pero otra de las limitaciones es el almacenamiento: Para permanecer en free tier, debe utilizar menos de 20GB al mes. Ya excedí ese número, y no entiendo por qué. Aún teniéndola apagada, cada día suma almacenamiento consumido durante el mes. No tiene activado ni backups ni le hice snapshots en ningún momento, por lo que esos no son los problemas. Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué es lo que consume GB de almacenamiento de mi instancia además de las tablas y datos de la base?